# Casting arguments from getopt

Tags: c, getopt, size-t

Suppose i have this code:

```
size_t n;  // my parameter

while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "n:")) != -1) {
  switch(c) {
  case 'n':
    n = optarg; // <=== HERE
    break;
  default:
    abort ();
  }
}
```

I am parsing command-line parameters using `getopt` GNU C function. If `n` datatype is `size_t`(an unsigned integer)...

How should I cast this value?
Should I cast this using `strtol`?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `strtol` is not a cast, but it is possibly what you want to do. (`strtoul` is a little more likely.)

Both will accept negative numbers (even though `strtoul` produces an `unsigned long`) so you might want to do some error-checking before you call the conversion function.

Read the `man strtoul` manpage for details.

You might also consider making `n` an `unsigned long` instead of a `size_t`.

Comment: Thank you, what about if I need `size_t` datatype, I do not need `unsigned long` because I just need few bits to store.

Comment: @Israel: probably `size_t` is `unsigned long` but it depends on your architecture. You could use `int` (or `unsigned int`) if you don't expect `n` to be very big. Personally, I only use `size_t` for the size of `malloc` allocations. Don't worry about bits. Worry about what the largest meaningful value can be.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
1. atoi(str)
2. atol(str)
3. atoll(str)
```

which is equivalent to

```
(int) strtol(nptr,(char **)NULL, 10)
strtol(nptr,(char **)NULL, 10)
strtoll(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)
```

Use strtol if you want the end pointer (to check whether there are more characters to read or if in fact you have read any at all) or a base other than 10. Otherwise, atol is fine.

It's better use strtol/ll as it will help to know the reason it the conversion fails whereas atoi/l/ll will just return 0.

Hope this might help you

Thanks